# How to display special characters - knowing its alt code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I want to know how to display some special characters from character map (using with <kbd>Alt</kbd>) when user type some key.

For example: display `¥`(Alt+0165) when type `\`, display `§`(Alt+0167) when type `[`.

I know that the following code display `z` if user type `a`. But I don't know for characters with <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == 'a')
     e.KeyChar = 'z';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the charmap.exe applet on Windows and copy/paste into your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think straight forward way must work correct:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == '[')
       e.KeyChar = '§';
   else if (e.KeyChar == '\\')
       e.KeyChar = '¥';
}
```

Just type those chars with Alt in Visual studio!

Comment: Maybe use a `Dictionary<char, char>` for the mapping if the list gets a little bit longer.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == '[')
       e.KeyChar = (char)167;
   else if (e.KeyChar == '\\')
       e.KeyChar = (char)165;
}
```